# NodeJS - express + mongoose + BAL with single connection

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new to `NodeJS` and I setup a new `express` app with `mongoose` and I have read a lot about how to manage the DB connection in this app.

I read that the best practice is to setup the connection to the `app.locals` of the `express` instance and that's good but my code look like something that is hard to maintain and complex.

In every endpoint I need to insert this first line:

```
 const db = req.app.locals.db;
```

And the code looks like that:

```js
const create = async (req, res) => {
    const db = req.app.locals.db;

    const sysUserModel = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
    };

    const model = new db.models.sys_user(sysUserModel);
    const sysUser = await model.save();

    res.json({
        status: true,
        data: sysUser
    });
};
```

I want to add a Business access layer with services to refactor my code and prevent decoupling in my code, but I can't find any articles or blog post about a single connection with express app and how to add services that uses the connection as a best practice.

I thought about passing every time the db connection to some service class but again it hard to maintain.

How you suggest to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need db object directly to access the database through mongoose. You just need access to your models. 
So just create a separate directory for models and you can import all the models in an index file inside that directory. Now, whenever you want to access db you just require in the models folder and access database from there.

File structure can be like this:-

```
models/
  user.js // user model
  post.js // post model
  comment.js  // comment model
  index.js
```

index.js file might look like this

```
module.exports = {
 User: require("./user"),
 Post: require("./post"),
 Comment: require("./comment")
}
```

File where you want to access db might look like this

```
const db = require(".../models");

const create = async (req, res) => {

    const sysUserModel = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
    };

    const user = new db.User(sysUserModel);
    const sysUser = await user.save();

    res.json({
        status: true,
        data: sysUser
    });
};
```